# keyup(), change(), events issue on IE8 (load image works only one time)

Tags: internet-explorer-8, png, radio-group, png-24

am front of a problem on IE8. (not tested on IE9)

this is my little programm with some HTML + Jquery

a picture worth a thousand words 
you can take a view here http://twixtop.lescigales.org/color/

i need five folders A B P C D

actually when you select a "MODEL",  the defaults values show in text input form on the left-sidebar  "W.png, W.png, W.png, X.png X.png"

```
    // Settings
   var settings = {
    "model":  "DIAM",
    "baseColor": "W",
    "sideColor": "W",
    "ambientColor": "W",
    "baseLight": "X",
    "centralColor": "X",
    "rendureference": "WXY3"
   };

   var options  = {
    "imageC": "images/[model]/C/[baseColor].png",
    "imageD": "images/[model]/D/[sideColor].png",
    "imageA": "images/[model]/A/[ambientColor].png",
    "imageB": "images/[model]/B/[baseLight].png",
    "imageP": "images/[model]/P/[centralColor].png",
    "renduZ": "WXY3-[model]-[ambientColor]-[baseLight]-[centralColor]-[baseColor][sideColor]-TG",
    "ValueModel": "[model]"


   }
   $('#customizer [type="radio"]').bind('click', function() {
   var el = $(this);
    settings[el.attr('name')] = el.attr('value');
    settingDigest();
   });



   // Show Var
   function settingDigest()
   {
    var imgC = options.imageC;
    var imgD = options.imageD;
    var imgA = options.imageA;
    var imgB = options.imageB;
    var imgP = options.imageP;
    var renZ = options.renduZ;
    var valueM = options.ValueModel;

    for(i in settings) {
     imgC = imgC.replace('['+i+']', settings[i]);
     imgD = imgD.replace('['+i+']', settings[i]);
     imgA = imgA.replace('['+i+']', settings[i]);
     imgB = imgB.replace('['+i+']', settings[i]);
     imgP = imgP.replace('['+i+']', settings[i]);
     renZ = renZ.replace('['+i+']', settings[i]);
     valueM = valueM.replace('['+i+']', settings[i]);
    }

// left sidebar input text keyup
    $('#avatar_C').val(imgC).keyup();
   $('#avatar_D').val(imgD).keyup();
   $('#avatar_A').val(imgA).keyup();
   $('#avatar_B').val(imgB).keyup();
   $('#avatar_P').val(imgP).keyup();
   $('#avatar_Z').val(renZ).keyup();
   $('#avatar_JADE').val(valueM).keyup();

   }
```

The problem appears when you select a color repeatedly only on IE8 for example:

1. select differents colors in the
   Base Panel (white, gray, red and one blue)
2. back already selected a color (white or gray)
3. **IE8 does not charge properly image**

i think there is a problem of cache ?? memory image ? i don't know ... 
I try to play with the functions .live(), .bind(), .blur(), .change(), ..
no way

already selected a button does not reload the image a second time if it has already been selected in advance...

I started to pull my hair.
f.....g internet explorer...

i have try differents things
    
emulate ie8 like an IE7...  // no result

All works on CHROME, FIREFOX, IE7, OPERA, SAFARI
awesome...

**EDIT 20 janv 2011**

this is my first post here..
sorry for my poor english...

there is a JSBIN for people want to help me.
**jsbin.com/ihiyi4/3**

1. Select a model (DIAMON or JADE) this load default images
2. Select differents colors in the Base Panel (white, gray, red and one blue)
3. back already selected a color (white or gray)
4. IE8 does not charge properly image

I do not understand why IE8 user's need to empty the cache to load again the image

Comment: Did you try running with the Script Debugger enabled (Hit F12, go to the sCRIPT tab) to see if there are any exceptions?

Comment: this because there is an attribute for the image ( complete = complete)